# Request is going to wrong handler in spring:

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am testing some feature in spring. My aim is to edit a record from a table. the below is the jsp code to dispay the existing records.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Telephone</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="emp" items="${employees}">
        <tr>
            <td>${emp.id}</td>
            <td>${emp.firstName}</td>
            <td>${emp.lastName}</td>
            <td>${emp.telephone}</td>
            <td>${emp.email}</td>
            <td><a href="<c:url value="getEmpForUpdate/${emp.id}" />">Update</a></td>
            <td><a>Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

I guess something is wrong with hiper link that i am using in the above code.

```
<a href="<c:url value="getEmpForUpdate/${emp.id}" />">Update</a>
```

when I click on a record the URL will be like below.

```
http://localhost:9876/SpringAnnotationDemo_Tomcat/getEmpForUpdate/4
```

its displaying form to edit the record. Below is my code which is using to edit the record.

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/updateEmployee">
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="firstName">F Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="lastName">L Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="telephone">Phone</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="telephone" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="email">E-Mail</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

After editing details in the above from, when i hit enter the URL should be like below
http://localhost:9876/SpringAnnotationDemo_Tomcat/updateEmployee

But it is like below
http://localhost:9876/SpringAnnotationDemo_Tomcat/getEmpForUpdate/updateEmployee

```
My controller method is like below
    @RequestMapping(value="/updateEmployee",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView updateEmployeeUsingObject(@ModelAttribute Employee employee){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        System.out.println(employee.getId());
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Can you please let me know where I am going wrong. why the URL is not as expected.

Comment: Please help me on this. Please let me know what is the best way to edit an record in Spirng MVC application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once you have navigated edit your page is at url http://localhost:9876/SpringAnnotationDemo_Tomcat/getEmpForUpdate so you need update/change your action to `"../updateEmployee"` since it is relative url

or better you give the url something like

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/updateEmployee" method="post">
```

Comment: The first options is not working. http://localhost:9876/SpringAnnotationDemo_Tomcat/updateEmployee this URL is being called and its giving the below error.

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /SpringAnnotationDemo_Tomcat/WEB-INF/jsps/updateEmployee.jsp

Comment: When I try second options its giving the below Error: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - javax.servlet.jsp.JspException cannot be resolved 
  to a type
 - javax.servlet.jsp.JspException cannot be resolved 
  to a type

Comment: Thanks I don't  know why now solutions are working fine now. THank you.